# Selenium Webdriver - passing bulk data with excel sheet by header name- more than 50 fields of form

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, jxl, dataprovider

I am looking for some solution where i want to pass 100s of records to the form where i am having more than 50 fields. I did some research for the testNG data providers but it looks like that it returns only strings so i feel that it will not be feasible to go with data providers as if its not good to pass 50 string arguments  to specific function. Also i did some research to read excel file and i get two ways that either i can go with the jxl or Apache poi but with that also i am not able to read the data by the column header as if i can not go with the row and column number of approach as i have so many fields that i need to work with. The reason behind that is that in future is one field has added to single form that its going to be rework and again its not feasible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxm44.png)

I have been following this link:
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/selenium-framework-design-selenium-tutorial-21/

for reading data column wise but any how i am not getting the records based on the column header. Do we have any other way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify where you need to send all this data? 00s of records to an online form? Please also list any errors you got, and if relevant, any related code.

Comment: I want to automate my test form.

I found the solution to get it done by apache poi. I have to test a form that contains more that 50 fields and i am goignto prepare one excel sheet for that and execute 100 or more record test for that same form with the help of excel sheet. I am not getting an idea that how should i manage this much data in class, which approach shall i go for - like using hash tables or collections. Which approach will be feasible. I have attached the file that contains the form of data. Do you have any link that i can refer for this kind of implementation.

Comment: Customer Data 
[0]
 ----Ldc Info---
 [LDCComm]
 [LDCOWCompany] 
 [LDCContract]
 [LDCCompanyName]
 [LDCTDSP]
 [LDCNO]
 [MeterNo]
 [LDCKeyName]
 [Street]
 [City]
 [zip]
 ----Cust Info---
 [CustCompDBA]
 [CustEtax]
 [CustGtax]
 [CustTaxCat]
 [CustTaxId]
 [CustSSN]
 [CustSteet]
 [CustCity]
 [CustZip]
 [CustRateClass]
 ---Contact---
 10 more fields
 ---Terms---
 10 More fields
 ---Comission--
 5 more fields
 ---Contract---
 15 more fields
[1]
 Same as Array [0]
[2]
 same as Array [0]
 |
 |
 |
[25]
 |
 |
 |
[50]
 |
 |
 |

[100] or more

Comment: I read data by column name in some automation that I wrote. I first map all the column headers in a HashMap<String, Integer> where String is the column name and Integer is the column index. Once you have the map, you can pass the column name that you want to read from and get the column index then read the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "testNG data providers but it looks like that it returns only strings" - incorrect.  It allows you to return a multidimensional array of type Object.  What kind of object you create is your own code.  You may choose to read from the excel, encapsulate all the fields in one object (your own pojo) or multiple objects and then the method argument can have just those object types declared and not the 50 strings.
2. Both jxl and poi are libraries to interact with excel.  If you want to have specific interaction with excel, like reading based on header, then you need to write code for that - it doesn't come out of the box. 
   If you are concerned about addition of one more column , then build your indices first by reading the header column, then put it in a relevant data structure and then go about reading your data.

Comment: I found the solution to get it done by apache poi. I have to test a form that contains more that 50 fields and i am goignto prepare one excel sheet for that and execute 100 or more record test for that same form with the help of excel sheet. I am not getting an idea that how should i manage this much data in class, which approach shall i go for - like using hash tables or collections. Which approach will be feasible. I have attached the file that contains the form of data. Do you have any link that i can refer for this kind of implementation.

Comment: here is the link of data format:

Customer Data 
[0]
 ----Ldc Info---
 [LDCComm]
 [LDCOWCompany] 
 [LDCContract]
 [LDCCompanyName]
 [LDCTDSP]
 [LDCNO]
 [MeterNo]
 [LDCKeyName]
 [Street]
 [City]
 [zip]
 ----Cust Info---
 [CustCompDBA]
 [CustEtax]
 [CustGtax]
 [CustTaxCat]
 [CustTaxId]
 [CustSSN]
 [CustSteet]
 [CustCity]
 [CustZip]
 [CustRateClass]
 ---Contact---
 10 more fields
 ---Terms---
 10 More fields
 ---Comission--
 5 more fields
 ---Contract---
 15 more fields
[1]
 Same as Array [0]
[2]
 same as Array [0]
 |
 |
 |
[25]
 |
 |
 |
[50]
 |
 |
 |

[100] or more

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved that with the help of apache poi. I created on centralized function that is returning the hashmap having title as an index. 
Here is that function:

Here is my main test function:

```
@Test(dataProvider="dpCreateNewCust")
  public void createNewCustomer(List<Map<String, String>> sheetList){   


            try{
                //Step 2. Login
                UtilityMethods.SignIn();

                for(Map<String, String> map : sheetList){
                    //Step 3. New Customer
                    if(map.get("Testcase").equals("Yes"))
                    {   
                        //Process with excel data
                        ProcessNewCustomer(map);                        
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println ("Login Exception Raised: <br> The exception get caught" + e);
            }           

  }

//My data provider 
@DataProvider(name = "dpCreateNewCust")  
    public  Object[][] dpCreateNewCust(){
       XLSfilename = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//src//watts//XLSFiles//testcust.xlsx";
      List<Map<String, String>> arrayObject = UtilityMethods.getXLSData(XLSfilename,Sheetname));
        return new Object[][] { {arrayObject } };
    }

//----GetXLSData Method in UtilityMethods Class :
 public static List<Map<String, String>> getXLSData(String filename, String sheetname)
    {
        List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Map<String, String>> sheetList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        try {     
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);

            //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
            XSSFWorkbook XLSbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first sheet from the workbook
            //HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            WorkSheet = XLSbook.getSheet(sheetname);            

            //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            int i = 0;
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = WorkSheet.iterator();

            while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                //For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                int j = 0;
                Map<String, String> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
                while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    if(i==0){
                        titleList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        String cellval = "";
                        switch(cell.getCellType()) {

                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                cellval = cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"";
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                cellval = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue())+"";
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                cellval = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                break;
                            default:
                                 break;
                        }
                        if(cellval!="")
                        {
                            valueMap.put(titleList.get(j), cellval);                                                         valueMap.put("ResultRow",String.valueOf(row.getRowNum()));
                            valueMap.put("ResultCol",String.valueOf(0));
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                }

                if(i!=0 && !valueMap.isEmpty()){
                    //System.out.println(valueMap);
                    sheetList.add(valueMap);
                }
                i++;
            }
            //System.out.println(sheetList);        System.exit(0);
            file.close();
            XLSbook.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sheetList;

    }
```